# Pivoting with multiple columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, pivot, tidyr

My data is in wide form and looks like below. The data includes names and four data columns.

```
df_wide <- data.frame(
  name = c("John", "Smith", "Tom", "Alice"),
  area = c("A", "A", "B", "B"),
  hello_1 = c(20, 30, 40, 70),
  hello_covered = c(60, 89, 76, 87),
  world_1 = c(55, 65, 20, 29),
  world_1_covered = c(87, 29, 43, 42)
)
```

I want to convert this to a long format where against each name, I get two rows and two data columns. The expectation is for that data to look like below

```
   name area medicine value covered
1  John    A  hello    20      60
2  John    A  world    55      87
3 Smith    A  hello    30      89
4 Smith    A  world    65      29
5   Tom    B  hello    40      76
6   Tom    B  world    20      43
7 Alice    B  hello    70      87
8 Alice    B  world    29      42
```

I tried using `pivto_longer` but was not very successful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could set `".value"` in `names_to` and supply one of `names_sep` or `names_pattern` to specify how the column names should be split.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df_wide %>%
  rename(world_covered = world_1_covered) %>%
  rename_with(~ sub("1$", "value", .x), ends_with('1')) %>%
  pivot_longer(
    3:6,
    names_to = c("medicine", ".value"),
    names_sep = "_"
  )

# # A tibble: 8 × 5
#   name  area  medicine value covered
#   <chr> <chr> <chr>    <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 John  A     hello       20      60
# 2 John  A     world       55      87
# 3 Smith A     hello       30      89
# 4 Smith A     world       65      29
# 5 Tom   B     hello       40      76
# 6 Tom   B     world       20      43
# 7 Alice B     hello       70      87
# 8 Alice B     world       29      42
```

Comment: This is amazing. Can we do it without column renaming? as i have additional columns in my data as `hello_2`, `hello_2_covered` etc.

Answer (score 4):

You can rename first to ease the pivoting:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df_wide %>% 
  rename_with(~ gsub("\\_1", "", .x)) %>% 
  rename_with(~ ifelse(grepl("_", .x), .x, paste(.x, "value", sep = "_")), -c(name, area)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(name, area), names_to = c("medicine", ".value"), names_sep = "_")

  name  area  medicine value covered
  <chr> <chr> <chr>    <dbl>   <dbl>
1 John  A     hello       20      60
2 John  A     world       55      87
3 Smith A     hello       30      89
4 Smith A     world       65      29
5 Tom   B     hello       40      76
6 Tom   B     world       20      43
7 Alice B     hello       70      87
8 Alice B     world       29      42
```

Answer (score 1):

one optional approach within the tidyverse - not as concise but possibly easier to comprehend:

```
df_wide %>%
    # make data long
    tidyr::pivot_longer(hello_1:world_1_covered, names_to = "medicine_pre", values_to = "value") %>%
    # remove one from before column names made into long format
    dplyr::mutate(medicine_pre = stringr::str_remove_all(medicine_pre, pattern = "_1")) %>%
    # split the before column names into two columns
    tidyr::separate(medicine_pre, into = c("medicine", "helper"), sep = "_") %>% 
    # make NAs to "value"
    dplyr::mutate(helper = dplyr::coalesce(helper, "value"))  %>%
    # make data wide again
    tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = helper, values_from = value)

# A tibble: 8 x 5
  name  area  medicine value covered
  <chr> <chr> <chr>    <dbl>   <dbl>
1 John  A     hello       20      60
2 John  A     world       55      87
3 Smith A     hello       30      89
4 Smith A     world       65      29
5 Tom   B     hello       40      76
6 Tom   B     world       20      43
7 Alice B     hello       70      87
8 Alice B     world       29      42
```

Answer (score 0):

An approach that should work on additional *hello_X*/*world_X* names, as these mark the **values**.

Either *hello_covered* or *work_1_covered* is an outlier of the pattern which is why an additional `mutate` of *medicine* is needed.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

pivot_longer(df_wide, -c(name, area), names_pattern = "(.*)_*.*_(.*)", 
             names_to = c("medicine", "nm")) %>% 
  mutate(nm = replace(nm, grepl("\\d", nm), "value"), 
         medicine = sub("_.*", "" , medicine)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = nm, values_from = value)
# A tibble: 8 × 5
  name  area  medicine value covered
  <chr> <chr> <chr>    <dbl>   <dbl>
1 John  A     hello       20      60
2 John  A     world       55      87
3 Smith A     hello       30      89
4 Smith A     world       65      29
5 Tom   B     hello       40      76
6 Tom   B     world       20      43
7 Alice B     hello       70      87
8 Alice B     world       29      42
```